# How to find datastore clusters presented to compute cluster?

Tags: powercli

I am using PowerCLI script calls within a rest service.  The rest service is being passed a bunch of data about new VM build requests.  For deployment, the only data (relevant to this question) I am getting is the vcenter server and the compute cluster name.  I need to figure out a way to determine what datastore cluster to deploy the VM on by using the compute cluster name.  If I do a get-cluster $clustername | fl * I don't see any correlation between the computer cluster and the datastore cluster.

If I get info on a VM host (get-vmhost $vmhost) within a cluster, I do see the datastoreIDlist as a property of the VMhost object and can see the datastores (not datastoreclusters) that are presented to it.  That's not ideal, but could be doable.

I know there is a relationship between compute clusters and storage that is presented to them within vcenter.  Why can't I find that in powercli?

Answer (score 0):

Here's one way to see those relationships

```
get-view -viewtype clustercomputeresource | % {$_.name + " `n " + $_.datastore + "`n"}
```

Not pretty, but this will list the datastore clusters available to each compute cluster:

```
 $ccr = get-view -viewtype ClusterComputeResource
 $pods = get-view -viewType StoragePod
 $pods | % {set-variable -name $_.name.replace("-","") -value $_.childentity.value} #my storage cluster names happen to contain hyphens, which do not play nice with get/set-variable, hence the .replace
 foreach ($c in $ccr) {
   $list = @()
   foreach ($vol in $c.datastore.value) { $match = $null
    $match = $pods | where {$_.childentity.value -contains $vol} | select -expand name
    if ($match) {$list += $match}
   } #close foreach vol
   set-variable -name $c.name -value $list
 } #close foreach c
$ccr.name | % {$_ + ": " + ((get-variable $_).value | select -unique) }
```